# Different results in Parallel Execution - Oracle

Tags: oracle

In my company's application there is a query in oracle using parallel execution (configured to 4 servers), it wasn't me who built it, but the developer put it that way for performance.

The query makes joins between views and tables and the weirdest thing is: sometimes it returns 11k results (incorrect), sometimes 27k results (correct).

After much research I found out that if I removed this parallel thing, it always returns the correct number: 27k. And if I increase the number of server to 6 or 7, it always returns the incorrect number: 11k.

The layout of the query is like this:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(NAME, 4) */ * FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT COLUMNS                           
    FROM VIEW
    JOIN TABLE1 ON (....)
    JOIN TABLE2 ON (....)
    JOIN TABLE3 ON (....)
    ORDER BY 3
) NAME
```

Anyone has any idea why? I don't know much about this subject.

Comment: It sounds like you've encountered a bug.  You'd need to report it to Oracle Support.  There is a good chance that there is a patch that you can apply or a workaround to the issue.

Comment: If `VIEW` in your query is actually a view then its underlying SQL statement might be of interest.

Comment: Your are hitting a bug for sure, I faced the same problem once migrating to 11G (I don't remember now if it was to R1 or R2). There are hidden parameters that can be applied to the Oracle engine, but an explain plan is needed. Most of the workarounds are to just disable Parallel query, but if you want to give it a try, please post your explain plan and confirm your database release.